# Symfony 2 : Add/update relation on condition otherwise remove it

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I have two entities : `User` and `Skill`.

They are linked via a Many-to-Many relation. 
This relation `UserSkill` contains extra information like `rating`. This rating goes from 0 to 10.

I do not want to have any relation where the rating is 0.

- I do not want to save new relation where rating is 0
- I want to remove relation when the updated rating becomes 0

I created prePersist and preUpdate event containing this code but it does not work :

```
$expertisesRatings = $entity->getUserSkillsRatings();
foreach($skillRatings as $skillRating) {
   $rate = $skillRating->getRating();
   if ($rate < 1) {
      $user->removeUserSkill($skillRating);   
      $skillRating->setTalent(null);
   }
}
```

It does nothing.
I have seen I can't manipulate relation in preUpdate event so I wonder if I need to use a onFlush or maybe a onPreFlush or maybe a complete different approach.

I hope I gave enough details.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try to handle that directly in the setter of `rating`. As you stated correctly, waiting for `prePersist` is actually to late.

Comment: An onFlush listener would work fine and I think is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Doctrine event listeners: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

With the listener class the entity itself does not have to change/remove itself, so it will allow you to do more advanced stuff.

Because the listener is a service you can inject the services you'd like.